# How to remove all characters except 'E' in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have strig like '`AA_0331L_02317_R5_P`' and i want remove all characters except 'E' from second part after splitting with _ character, so here it is 0331N should become 0331 and if it comes like `0331E` , then it should become `0331E` .ie simply if i have i string like AA_0331N_02317_R5_P , then i want to be `AA_0331_02317_R5_P` and if i have a `AA_0331E_02317_R5_P` ,then it should be `AA_0331E_02317_R5_P`. I did like as shown below without any luck

```
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'AA_0331L_02317_R5_P' , '[^_]+', 1, 2 ), '[^0-9]', '')  
FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with s as (
select 'AA_0331L_02317_R5_P' str from dual union all
select 'AA_0331E_02317_R5_P' str from dual)
select str,
regexp_replace(regexp_substr(str, '[^_]+_[^_]+'), '[^E]$') || regexp_replace(str, '[^_]+_[^_]+', '', 1, 1) new_str
from s;

STR                            NEW_STR
------------------------------ ------------------------------
AA_0331L_02317_R5_P            AA_0331_02317_R5_P
AA_0331E_02317_R5_P            AA_0331E_02317_R5_P
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like the following -- keeping in mind that `REGEXP_REPLACE()` will return the original string if nothing is actually replaced. Here I'm using backreferences (if Oracle regexes had lookahead I could have omitted the 2nd capturing group and backreference):

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT 'AA_0331L_02317_R5_P' AS myvalue
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AA_0331N_02317_R5_P'
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'AA_0331E_02317_R5_P'
      FROM dual
)
SELECT myvalue
     , REGEXP_REPLACE(myvalue, '^([^_]+_[^_]+)[^E](_)', '\1\2') mynewvalue
  FROM mytable;

MYVALUE                    MYNEWVALUE
-------------------------  -------------------------
AA_0331L_02317_R5_P        AA_0331_02317_R5_P
AA_0331N_02317_R5_P        AA_0331_02317_R5_P
AA_0331E_02317_R5_P        AA_0331E_02317_R5_P
```